# Development workflow on Sinatra/React application

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, sinatra

**First off, I'm relatively new to Rails and Node.js development, so please forgive me if my explanation lacks the correct terminology.**

I'm using Sinatra for the routing and API because its easy for me to understand vs. writing the API in something like Express. For the client side, I'm using React and making calls to the Sinatra API to get the data.

During development, I run the Sinatra backend on a port (running `rackup`. And separately run the client side w/ Express on a separate port. I use `gulp` to transpile the jsx.

What I'm wondering is if this workflow makes sense? Is there an easier way in which I could build everything using `rackup` including transpiling the jsx?

Would I be better off just building the front and backend API using Express?

Comment: This is the type of question for which the best answer is: "it depends". Normally, I would say that decoupling your client and server side into two separate codebases is a good thing because you can scale them differently, you can deploy them independently and so on. On the other hand, if your application is a small scale one, it introduces additional complexities that might be not needed in your case.

Comment: Is there any way to run the Sinatra server via Gulp or Grunt? Would that be possible solution to run both the backend and the frontend together?

Comment: With grunt or gulp you can run anything that is executable in cmd/terminal so yes. I think you can run both together, if you refer to automating the tasks with grunt/gulp